# How to remove a File from /usr/share/applications on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, command-line, rm

I tried to remove a file named "JDownloader 2 Update & Rescue" from `/usr/share/applications` directory but couldn't delete.

This terminal command didn't work:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/JDownloader 2 Update & Rescue
```

properties command like shows

```
/bin/sh "/opt/jd2/JDownloader2Update"
```

but **/opt** there is no Files or directory for JDownloader.

Comment: Firstly if you have space in file name you'll have to use \'s. Secondly `JDownloader 2 Update & Rescue` is probably not the actual file name, it's just the name specified in the `.desktop` file. Try `ls /usr/share/applications/` and find out the correct file name. It should be of the form "`filename.desktop`".

Comment: Try `whereis JDownloader` in terminal.

Comment: On my system (also having JD2 installed) the `.desktop` file is `~/.local/share/applications/JDownloader 2 Update & Rescue-0.desktop`. May I ask why you want to remove it in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

The name you are interpreting as a file name is the name provided for the Desktop Launcher.  The actual file is a file with a `*.desktop` extension.

You can locate the name of the launcher file (`*.desktop`) from the terminal by entering the `/usr/share/applications` folder, then search the contents of the desktop files for the filename.

Since I don't have your program installed I'll use a program installed on my computer as an example of the steps for the search.  I'll search for the `Terminal` launcher.  When you perform the steps, use `JDownloader` for your search string.  You can use more characters of the name if it brings up too many hits.

*(The line with the `$` prefex represent commands typed.  The other lines are terminal output.)*

```
$ cd /usr/share/applications
$ egrep -l "Terminal"
debian-uxterm.desktop
debian-xterm.desktop
emacs24-term.desktop
exo-terminal-emulator.desktop
gnome-terminal.desktop
mono-runtime-terminal.desktop
```

Those are the files that have `Name=Terminal` as an entry in the `*.desktop` filename.  Now I pick from the output list which one I want to delete.

Since there are more than one, I'll examine the file first with Gedit.  In this case:

```
 $ gedit gnome-terminal.desktop
```

If that's the one you can remove it with:

```
$ sudo rm gnome-terminal.desktop
```

Usually I move a system file to a temporary area before deleting it.  Then I make sure the change performs as expected.  Then I permanently delete the file.

**The GUI way:**

I presented the **terminal** method in my first example, because that was your method in your question.  You can also use a GUI search, which may be substantially easier.

Bring up the `/usr/share/applications` folder in a file browser.  This will show the files by there `Launcher Name`, not the actual file name.  This is the name you are seeing in the Launcher.  After you have brought up the list of file, you can point and click to delete.

```
$ sudo -H nautilus /usr/share/applications
```

***Note:***

You could also remove the file by uninstalling the application you installed that brought the Launcher to your system.

Since the file, from your description, is installed in `/opt`, it's an indication that it didn't come from the default repository.  So you'll have to look in package's **Readme** description to find the steps for uninstalling.